# How to find max difference between the sum of children using a BST?

Tags: algorithm, binary-tree, pseudocode

How would you efficiently go about finding the node where (X<sub>L</sub> - X<sub>R</sub>) is the maximum, where X<sub>L</sub> is the sum of X's left sub-tree and X<sub>R</sub> is the sum of X's right sub-tree by only using O(1) extra space outside of the tree (i.e. not using extra space within each node)?

Comment: just do a dfs that returns sum of subtree and keep globally your max difference

Comment: @juvian Strictly speaking, dfs is not O(1). It needs O(height) space for stack.

Comment: @user58697 otherwise not possible ^^

Comment: If there are no updates to made to the tree, add an extra sum field to your Node class and store subtree sums there.